# Line break in y axis title

Tags: r, ggplot2, line-breaks, axis-labels, yaxis

[I want the y axis labe in two rows; line break after evolved](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9BjRO.png)I am having problem in getting the line break in y axis title. It contains suprescript and subscript and I am using following code:

```
 ylab(bquote("Cumulative CO" [2] * " evolved (mg CO" [2]*"-C kg"^-1* "soil)")) +
  xlab("Incubation time (days)") +
```

I want line break after evolved. I have tried using \n and cannot get the desired result.

```
 ylab(bquote("Cumulative CO" [2] * " evolved (mg CO" [2]*"-C kg"^-1* "soil)")) +
  xlab("Incubation time (days)")
```

I tried `\n` but I get "evolved" in the upper row and other sentence in the second row.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. To help others help you, please take the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour and EDIT your question so that it meets the guidelines provided here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: We don't have any of your data in order to run your code, which is seemingly incomplete anyway, and we also can't see any of your output. It's unclear what the problem is, what you want to change, or what you want to change it to

Comment: I have attached the plot here. The data file is really large to upload here. I just need the code for the axis labs. I just want to arrange the units (seen in the ylab tittle) in separate rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the atop function:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  ylab(expression(atop("Cumulative CO" [2] * "", paste("evolved (mg CO" [2]*"-C kg"^-1* "soil)"))))
```

[image]